# JSF/JSP - Beginner Question

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf

I've recently dipped my toes into JBoss Seam and naturally have ton to learn but having had a hands on approach so far with looking at code and trying to write my own seam applications I've looking for understanding on below:

I've come across the following peace of code which i cannot see what it is trying to do which is triggered is called when user clicks a button:

```
    <h:commandButton value="Save" type="button" onclick="return userAction(this);" title="User Actions">
            <f:param value="#{user.codePk}" name="userCode"/>
            <h:inputHidden value="#{user.codePk}" id="code"/>
        </h:commandButton>
```

which calls a javascript function that open a window to display stock on hand:

```
   var pk = document.getElementById("product:code").value;
   window.open('<%=basePath1%>jsp/stockOnHand.faces?Code='+pk,"abcd");
```

I know that **stockOnHand.faces** is just stockOnHand.jsp and that stockOnHand.jsp contains has a table where stock on hand of a given product is shown in all stores.

I don't get how the part from **?Code='+pk,"abcd"** works. Is it similar to how it is done in Java where you can pass parameters to a function matching its signature for example

```
foo(int v, string s);
```

I hope this isn't too ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a string concatenation. The JS `window.open` function has the following signature:

```
open (URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])
```

The first argument `URL` in your example is a concatenation of the given string and the variable `pk`.  The second argument `windowName` is `abcd`.